# How to write testcases for a piece of logic?

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing, tdd

I want to learn how to write testcases for a piece of logic like unit tests. Now I am not concerned about any specific framework or language, just wanted to know how can I get learn to write input-output pairs that cover all of the possible input domain?

Hey can you people suggest me some strategies more like andres suggested like equivalence partitioning or some books in which I can read this?

Comment: It's unclear to me what kind of logic you are looking to write testcases for.
Could you include an example of what you want to test in your question?

Comment: @MiguelvandeLaar I think the question is about how to make sure you're writing all relevant test cases for any unit under test. The exact logic is not relevant for the question. Of course, the answer to this might disappoint Yashdeep :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is fool-proof, and the general case of "how do I know I'm testing every relevant scenario?" is "you can't know that", but there are approaches that attempt to systematize the coverage of relevant test cases.

With [Equivalence Partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_partitioning), you attempt to define an equivalence relation between groups of input data, and then only test one example of each equivalence relation. For example, possible groupings of input integers could be (depending on the algorithm under test, of course), "negative", "zero" and "positive".

Another technique is [Boundary Value Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary-value_analysis), where you pick a extreme or boundary values in the range of possible inputs.

Yet another testing technique is, instead of writing each scenario by hand, picking a property of your algorithm and telling a testing framework to verify it by generating random test cases for it. Frameworks like [QuickCheck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCheck) or ScalaCheck will attempt to find counterexamples that break your property, in which case they will tell you something like "I tried with input -1 and your property failed".

All these techniques come with limitations, but are good guidelines when writing tests.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a pure function, IE one that doesn't rely on any internal state carried over between calls, you would want to generate something like a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table). As @KilianFoth notes in his answer this is generally impractical for anything interesting. Since as soon as you pass in something like an integer you have a huge possible input set, and with a string it becomes effectively infinite.

In these situations the goal is to find useful cases that imply that the whole range works without exhaustively testing it. For example not knowing the content of the function you might try, the minimum value, -100,000,000, -1, 0, 1, 100,000,000, and max value as your input set to see what happens. For an arbitrary string argument you'd try a inputs like null, "", "a", "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "!@#$%^&**(){}|:"<>[]\;',./?`~", and "ǳשࣚ"(unicode for those of you looking at just blocks).

This would all be considered [black box testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) where you don't look at the function. In most software situations you can go look at the software and try to design an input to drive into all of the cases written inside of the function. If there is a special case that only happens if the integer argument is 3, then be sure 3 makes the list of inputs you test with.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you can't.

If the task you're programming is large enough that it's easier to write a computer program than to do it by hand, then the number of possible input/output pairs is probably too big to be tested exhaustively.

But writing a test case against every instance of a *previously encountered* error goes a long way towards code that handles all the relevant cases correctly.

Comment: Add that typically we don't need/want to exhaustively cover the entire domain _anyway_; we just choose common cases at various edges of the domain axes, numerical overflow boundaries, and so forth.

Comment: Elaborating on what @BarryTheHatchet said, there are techniques to partition the problem space (like Equivalence Class Testing) in order to write tests that cover all (or most) relevant cases.